# Accessing the Stereo in a '96 Infiniti G20

Tags: troubleshooting, audio

I do some of my own repair work on my car, a 96 Infiniti G20. Since I got it, the front speakers haven't been working and I want to fix them. How can I troubleshoot the problem? I assume it's either the speakers themselves or the stereo.

How can I remove my console panel to get at the stereo?
How can I easily test the stereo?

note: my cd player doesn't have a removable faceplate

Here is a picture of my console

[image: picture of console]

Answer (score 1):

To remove the radio you should just be able to unscrew the faceplate holding it in and then unplug the electrical connectors from the back of it as you pull it out. However if you need to follow the cables you may need to remove the dash itself, so a quick guide on how to do that:

- Remove the glove compartment by removing the screws under and inside the glove compartment and then pulling it out.
- Remove the radio - as already described
- With the doors open, unscrew all the screws and bolts around the dashboard
- Pull the dashboard forward enough so you can unplug the electrical connectors behind it.
- You can then slide the dashboard out the passenger side door.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My cd player doesn't have a removable faceplate and has no screws. I did notice there are 4 screws on my console, but when I took them out, it is still held in from the top. I'm not sure how to fully remove it- I added a pic to my question if that helps make sense of it.

Comment: You may have to remove the large white plastic console to access the screws that let you remove the radio from the dash. That's kind of how my deck-swap in a Caravan worked out.

I can't really tell you how to do it, but I'll see if there's a guide online for your vehicle.

Update: http://www.carradiorepair.com/pdfs/infiniti-g20.pdf

See if that helps!

Answer (score 1):

The white faceplate should pull straight off. Pull gently, most of them have clips that hold them in, be careful there may be some screws in the bottom near the cigarette lighter. After that there should be some screws visible to the right and left of the radio, removing those will let you slide it out. As for testing find the wiring diagram for the radio and determine what color the wires are that go to the speakers. You can use an ohm meter to check the speakers from the harness at the radio with the radio unplugged. They should be 4 ohms each, note some of the high end factory systems may have an amp between the radio and the speakers, that's where the wiring diagram comes in.